# Bootstrap Infinite carousel (loop) multi-Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

i am creating Testimonial For my project, I want to show only  3 Face indicators and remaining hide on click Left and right Control it should appear by replacing 3rd Face indicator and same goes for auto play,

Any Suggestions for newbie it would be useful

Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4v63g3L/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">
                <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                    <!-- Quote 1 -->
                    <div class="item active">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Quote 2 -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Quote 3 -->
                    <div class="item">
                        <blockquote>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,ore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut eni !</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Bottom Carousel Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><img class="img-responsive " src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mantia/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg" alt="">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev -->
               <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //carousel options
    $('#quote-carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: 20000,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Babu, I am not exactly sure what you would like to achieve but I gather the following:

- Hide controls and show controls when first/last slides are active?
or
- Hide controls completely?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not exactly there you can see three face indicator below i want two more but it should be in hide on completing 3rd one 4th and then fifth has to come , am sorry for poor explanation hope you got my point [link] (https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/infinite-carousel-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want like this?

```
jQuery("#quote-carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event, fromIndex, toIndex) {

    var active  =   jQuery(event.target).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active');
    var from    =   active.index();
    var next    =   jQuery(event.relatedTarget);
    var to_slide=   next.index();

    if (to_slide>2) {
        var hide_slide = parseInt(to_slide) - 3;
        jQuery('.carousel-indicators li[data-slide-to="'+to_slide+'"]').css({"display":"inline-block"});
        jQuery('.carousel-indicators li[data-slide-to="'+hide_slide+'"]').css({"display":"none"});
    } else{
        var hide_slide = parseInt(to_slide) + 3;
        jQuery('.carousel-indicators li[data-slide-to="'+to_slide+'"]').css({"display":"inline-block"});
        jQuery('.carousel-indicators li[data-slide-to="'+hide_slide+'"]').css({"display":"none"});
    } 
});
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/n4v63g3L/3/)

Comment: yeaa Superb Thanks a lot vel, one more help tell me how did you do that ?

Comment: I have done this in one of my project for testimonials